# c# how to find the largest number of 4 text boxes/results

Tags: c#

I have 4 text boxes and i would like to find the largest number of the 4, what methods are there that isnt a loop, these text boxes are total scores from 4 teams, the last button is the box that will show the largest number

i have to enter each value (value 1 to 5) in each button, and the result is the largest number of the four, i will be making these values up

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int value1 = 0;
   int value2 = 0;
   int value3 = 0;
   int value4 = 0;
   int value5 = 0;
   int result = 0;

   if (Int32.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out value1) && Int32.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out value2) && Int32.TryParse(textBox6.Text, out value3) && Int32.TryParse(textBox14.Text, out value4) && Int32.TryParse(textBox13.Text, out value5))

   {
      result = value1 + value2 + value3 + value4 + value5;
      textBox21.Text = result.ToString();
   }

}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int value1 = 0;
   int value2 = 0;
   int value3 = 0;
   int value4 = 0;
   int value5 = 0;
   int result = 0;

   if (Int32.TryParse(textBox11.Text, out value1) && Int32.TryParse(textBox10.Text, out value2) && Int32.TryParse(textBox9.Text, out value3) & Int32.TryParse(textBox8.Text, out value4) && Int32.TryParse(textBox15.Text, out value5))

   {
      result = value1 + value2 + value3 + value4 + value5;
      textBox22.Text = result.ToString();
   }
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int value1 = 0;
   int value2 = 0;
   int value3 = 0;
   int value4 = 0;
   int value5 = 0;
   int result = 0;

   if (Int32.TryParse(textBox7.Text, out value1) && Int32.TryParse(textBox5.Text, out value2) && Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out value3) & Int32.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out value4) && Int32.TryParse(textBox12.Text, out value5))

   {
      result = value1 + value2 + value3 + value4 + value5;
      textBox23.Text = result.ToString();
   }
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int value1 = 0;
   int value2 = 0;
   int value3 = 0;
   int value4 = 0;
   int value5 = 0;
   int result = 0;

   if (Int32.TryParse(textBox20.Text, out value1) && Int32.TryParse(textBox19.Text, out value2) && Int32.TryParse(textBox18.Text, out value3) & Int32.TryParse(textBox17.Text, out value4) && Int32.TryParse(textBox16.Text, out value5))

   {
      result = value1 + value2 + value3 + value4 + value5;
      textBox24.Text = result.ToString();
   }
}

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: Did you intend to use Bitwise ANDs in your `if` statements?

Comment: i dont know but it works @EatatJoes

Comment: If not, then you shouldn't. Do you know how it works? @lAbdi

Comment: Do you want to find the largest number or the sum of the text box .Arrray or other collection can sort the result and easy to get the lagest number or the sum of them. And one more thing, I think you should use double "&" in the if condiction.

Comment: okay i have doubled the &, i would like to find the largest number out of 4 text boxes (textBox21, 22,23 and 24) @Jaycee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, however this might help you out

Make life easier with some short hand extension methods

**Extension Methods**

```
public static class TextBoxExtensions
{
   public static int GetInt(this TextBox source)
   {
      // if TextBox null just return 0
      if (source == null)
      {
         return 0;
      }
      // if it is a valid int, return it, otherwise return 0
      // not we use string, in case someone put a space at the start or end
      return int.TryParse(source.Text.Trim(), out var value) ? value : 0;
   }

   public static bool HasValidInt(this TextBox source)
   {
      // if TextBox null or its not an int return false
      // otherwise return true
      return source != null && int.TryParse(source.Text.Trim(), out var _);
   }
}
```

**Helper function to get Max**

```
// helper function, this does not use a loop
// get the max of all textboxes
private int GetMax(params TextBox[] args)
{
   return args.Where(x => x.HasValidInt()) // remove any invalid numbers
               .Select(x => x.GetInt()) // project to int
               .Max(); //get the max of all
}
```

**Your existing code**

using the extension methods

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // this is just a better way to validate your text boxes with the extension method
   if (textBox1.HasValidInt() && textBox2.HasValidInt() && textBox3.HasValidInt() && textBox4.HasValidInt())
   {
      // get the ints from all text boxes using extension method
      var result = textBox1.GetInt() + textBox2.GetInt() + textBox3.GetInt() + textBox4.GetInt();
      textBox6.Text = result.ToString();
   }
}
```

**Get max Version 1**

This doesn't use a loop. However, does use `Linq`

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // get the max of all textboxes using the helper method
   textBox6.Text = GetMax(textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4).ToString();
}
```

**Get max Version 2**

This doesn't use a loop. However, does use `Math.Max`

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // this is just a better way to validate your text boxes with the extension method
   if (textBox1.HasValidInt() && textBox2.HasValidInt() && textBox3.HasValidInt() && textBox4.HasValidInt())
   {
      // use math to get the max
      var result = 0;
      result = Math.Max(result, textBox1.GetInt());
      result = Math.Max(result, textBox2.GetInt());
      result = Math.Max(result, textBox3.GetInt());
      result = Math.Max(result, textBox4.GetInt());
      textBox6.Text = result.ToString();
   }
}
```

## Additional Resources

[**Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

> Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types
>   without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise
>   modifying the original type. Extension methods are a special kind of
>   static method, but they are called as if they were instance methods on
>   the extended type. For client code written in C#, F# and Visual Basic,
>   there is no apparent difference between calling an extension method
>   and the methods that are actually defined in a type.

[**Getting Started with LINQ in C#**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq)

> This section contains basic background information that will help you
>   understand the rest of the LINQ documentation and samples.

**[Int32.TryParse Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)**

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
>   integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the operation
>   succeeded.

**[params (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params)**

> By using the params keyword, you can specify a method parameter that
>   takes a variable number of arguments.
>
> You can send a comma-separated list of arguments of the type specified
>   in the parameter declaration or an array of arguments of the specified
>   type. You also can send no arguments. If you send no arguments, the
>   length of the params list is zero.

**[Enumerable.Where Method (IEnumerable, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx)**

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

**[Enumerable.Select Method (IEnumerable, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx)**

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

**[Enumerable.Max Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max(v=vs.110).aspx)**

> Returns the maximum value in a sequence of values.

**[Math.Max Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.max(v=vs.110).aspx)**

> Returns the larger of two specified numbers.

---

**Comment from IFebles**

> It also can be done with this (segmentating the TextBoxs within
>   panels):

```
var values = panel1.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                    .Where(obj => obj is TextBox)
                    .Select(obj => int.Parse(obj.Text))
                    .Max();
```

**knowing that it can throw a `FormatException` if any input can't be parsed. Not as neat as the given answer, but also good to know.**

Comment: It also can be done with this (segmentating the TextBoxs within panels): `var maxValue = panel1.Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(obj => obj is TextBox).Select(obj => int.Parse(obj.Text)).Max();` knowing that it can throw a `FormatException` if any input can't be parsed. Not as neat as the given answer, but also good to know.